# Spring Cloud Contract HTTP output body from file dynamically from request

Tags: groovy, spring-cloud-contract

It would be a nice and agile way to provide "test data" for mock server if it were possible to get a response file name from request dynamically. I wonder if someone could find some kind of workaround to implement something like :

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {

    request {
        url "/one/two/three/response"
        method GET()
    }

    response {
        status OK()
        headers {
            contentType applicationJson()
        }
        body ( file( '' + $(consumer(fromRequest().path(3)), producer("response")) + '.json'))
    }
}
```

Or it just is not possible to determine output file dynamically from request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do such things unfortunately. You would have to create the body manually and its part should have references to `fromRequest`.

Comment: OK. That feature can be achieved with Wiremock (standalone) using switch --global-response-templating + what it needs to mapping. I did not try : does Spring Cloud Contract have that option on? Then you could load that mapping with http post?

Comment: You could achieve the same by putting such manuały created  stub to the stub jar. Then stub runner will upload it to the started wiremock. Sc contract can register additional wiremock  extensions though. Also if the file contains the mustache templates then maybe it would work anyways. You'd have to check it out

Comment: Thanks. We (!!) very much appreciate these real time replies :)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the request from within a seperate json file to put the value into a specific property. For example in the .json file you can do something like

```
{
   "foo": "{{{ request.path.[3] }}}"
}
```

What you suggest however will not work. You can not dynamically create or select a different json file.